# Assuming each letter in a word has an assigned number, like 'a' = 3, 'b' = 2, how can I print the sum of all letters in a word?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

For example:

```
Welcome to the Scribble Scorer Enter word: mostboringest
Word: mostboringest Score: 32.5
```

Each letter in mostboringest has a number value. The program added up all the values and printed a score.

How can I code this in Python using while loops and for loops?

Here is what I have so far:

```
user_input = input('Welcome to the Scribble Scorer; Enter Word:')

i = {'e': 1, 't': 1.5, 'a': 2, 'i': 2, 'n': 2, 's': 2, 'h': 2.5, 'r': 2.5, 'd': 2.5, 'l': 3, 'u': 3, 'c': 3.5, 'm': 3.5, 'f': 4, 'w': 4.5, 'y': 4.5, 'p': 5, 'g': 5, 'b': 5.5, 'v': 5.5, 'k': 5.5, 'q': 5.5, 'j': 6, 'x': 6, 'z':6}
```

Prompt the user for a word (you can just ask them for any string). For this program, we will score lower case letters only!

Using a loop, calculate the score for the word (string) provided. You don't need to check for errors (like specifying more than one word), but your program should not crash or fail if given an incorrect input. All point values are given in the comments in the code cell for you. If you find a character other than the ones below, assign it a value of -1 point.

Print the word and the score.

Keep repeating these steps until the user enters nothing ('').

```
Welcome to the Scribble Scorer Enter word: mostboringest
Word: mostboringest Score: 32.5
Enter word: feedlebart
Word: mostboringest Score: 24.0
Enter word:
```

Comment: There are numerous ways to approach this problem. What have you tried? Are you stuck? Do you have any code? Are you getting any errors? Are you familiar with dictionaries? What is the letter -> value mapping? Are uppercase letters worth the same as lowercase? What about punctuation?

Comment: You may start by learning how to read each letter of a string. Where are the values corresponding to the letters stored? In what data structure?

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Edit your original post.

Comment: You already posted this question earlier (which you now deleted): https://stackoverflow.com/q/69716509/2745495. It was closed as "needs to be more focused" because this is basically a dump of all the assignment requirements, and then expecting a full-on solution. I recommend breaking the problem into smaller steps: how to iterate over the characters of a string, how to look up values from a dictionary using a key, how to sum values with a loop, etc.)

Comment: @GinoMempin Thanks for the feedback. I was working late on this assignment and I was running out of time so I rushed a question in without making it easier for others. Even though I got an answer and managed to figure it out, I will break down the problem next time and piece together what I know. Coding isn't just plugging in and hoping to get a solution, it's breaking it down and understanding what you need to do. Again thank you for the heads up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by using a dictionary which maps letters to a specific weight value. With this, you can iterate through your string and add up the total value accumulated for every character in the string.

```py
letterValues = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
    "g": 1,
    "t": 6
    # .. and so on.
}

string = "mostboringest"

totalValue = 0
for char in string: # For every character in our string.
    totalValue += letterValues.get(char, 0) # Add it to our total.

print(totalValue)
```

Comment: You could get rid of the `if` statement and use `letterValues.get(char, 0)` instead.

Comment: Or `-1`, according to OP's homework instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the optimization tip, I have actually been looking for a way to get rid of that pesky `if` check to determine if a key exists in a dictionary before trying to access it.

Comment: Yeah, it's nice. `dict.get` defaults to `None` as the fallback. You can return anything you want, including another `dict.get` call.

Answer (score 2):

You could use sum and map. If you have non-mapped character, you will also need to filter out the None mappings:

```
sum(filter(None,map(i.get,user_input)))
```

Comment: If the mapping is converted to a `defaultdict` that returns 0 for example as a default value, I think you can actually skip the `filter` usage

Comment: You could indeed. A defaultdict (from collections) would also allow the default value to be something other than zero if need be.

Comment: Why not `sum(i.get(char, -1) for char in user_input)`? Filtering and mapping are overkill for something this straightforward.

Comment: Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: Too many similar answers at this point.

Comment: I disagree, for example I see no other answer is defaulting invalid letters to -1 at the moment :-)

Comment: I mention as much in a comment. Plus the question has been closed :D

Answer (score 0):

`like 'a' = 3, 'b' = 2`

```py
mapping = {'a': 3, 'b': 2}
mapping['a'] + mapping['b']  # = 5
```

Edit (above, to original example, below to a whole word)

```py
mapping = {'e': 1, 't': 1.5, 'a': 2, 'i': 2, 'n': 2, 's': 2, 'h': 2.5, 'r': 2.5, 'd': 2.5, 'l': 3, 'u': 3, 'c': 3.5, 'm': 3.5, 'f': 4, 'w': 4.5, 'y': 4.5, 'p': 5, 'g': 5, 'b': 5.5, 'v': 5.5, 'k': 5.5, 'q': 5.5, 'j': 6, 'x': 6, 'z':6}

example = 'weird'  # was `word`, there is no `o`
score = sum(mapping[i] for i in example)
print(score)
```

Comment: How does this code handle a whole word?

Comment: ok i added a better example

Comment: Just a tip, `sum()` accepts iterators, no need for square brackets: `sum(d[w] for w in example)`

Comment: ah yes you're right (edited)

Comment: Also note that OP has already provided a mapping. I suggest editing your answer to include their mapping and example inputs.

Comment: @ddejohn gotcha, ty, edited

Comment: Cheers, +1 and welcome to SO